# Is there a way to know which number of the list without index in Python?

Tags: python

I'm solving a problem, for example
w[0]=16*5 # K is the number of terms to be added.

`for n in range(1,K+1) : long_div(w,5*5,w)`

Assuming that long_div(w,5*5,w) is called K times,

I would like to put the values of 16*(1/5), 16*(1/5)^3, 16*(1/5)^5... into w,

If i call w, I think it is impossible to grasp it without index. is this 
possible in python?

The problem feature, function and parameter is not to be touched.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can use `n` as index value and then put it in your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always call functions with variables. In this case, you are calling `long_div` with the variable `w` which must be defined elsewhere.

All you need to do is replace the occurrences of `w` in your function call with the formula that you gave in the question. To do this, it will be easiest to create a `local` variable that will hold the outcome of the formula.

```
for n in range(1, K+1):
    f = 16 * (1/5) ** (n*2 - 1)
    long_div(f, 5*5, f)
```

we use the formula: `16 * (1/5) ** (n*2 - 1)` here as it produces the sequence of calculations that you put in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "you must always call functions with variables"?

Answer (score 0):

```
#This would solve your problem
```

## using python 2.xxx

## let us take k as 4

K = 4

## let us assign the values of w to a list

w = [16*(1/5), 16*(1/5)^3, 16*(1/5)^5]

## now we loop and assign them

for n in range(1,K+1): 
    print long_div(w[n], 5*5 , w[n])

Comment: yikes, quite the formatting scheme you got going on